# Regex - remove everything before and include the current criteria

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to create a pattern and to remove everything before and including the patter if possilble.

My sample text is:

```
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 32546 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 22:48:59 UTC Wed Jan 6 2021 by bobb
! NVRAM config last updated at 22:35:10 UTC Mon Nov 2 2020 by johns
!
version 16.10
```

Id like anything before version removing, I didn't mind the first ! so I have the below which gets the NVRAM line

```
^! NVRAM.+
```

now what would my python/regex look like to remove that NVRAM line and everything before it?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\A(?:(?!! NVRAM).*\n)*! NVRAM.*\n*
\A(?:[\s\S]*?\n)?! NVRAM.*\n*
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/mEW1S3/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/mEW1S3/1).

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:(?!! NVRAM).*\n)*` - zero or more sequences of lines that do not start with `! NVRAM`
- `(?:[\s\S]*?\n)?` - an optional sequence (it is necessary if the line starting with `! NVRAM` is the first line) any zero or more chars, as few as possible, up to the first newline char that is followed with the subsequent subpatterns
- `! NVRAM.*` -  `! NVRAM` and the rest of the line
- `\n*` - optional zero or more newlines.